# Unable to hit conditional expressional index

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with around 20 million records with an index over a `created_at` timestamp field. The size of the index is huge and even with an index scan, querying the table by that field is not fast enough (7 seconds). So I decided to play a bit with smaller expressional indexes. The thing is the planner never hits them and is going for a sequential scan instead. What am I doing wrong?

```
db=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx;
 count
----------
 19527175
(1 row)
```

The conditional expressional index is defined as:

```
CREATE INDEX xxx_idx ON xxx (DATE(created_at)) WHERE created_at > '2016-01-01';
```

That fraction represents just 2% of the entire data.

```
db=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx WHERE created_at > '2016-01-01';
 count
---------
 335895
(1 row)
```

Yet, when trying to use the index by specifying the same **condition** and **expression**, a sequential scan is used instead.

```
db=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE DATE(created_at) > '2016-01-01';
                              QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on xxx  (cost=0.00..1533675.37 rows=6509853 width=884) (actual time=23.104..120704.554 rows=319278 loops=1)
   Filter: (date(created_at) > '2016-01-01'::date)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 19208882
 Planning time: 0.245 ms
 Execution time: 120748.839 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` implemented in Postgres differently from MySQL. Check out this link: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Comment: The query expects 6553094 to be returned by the condition. As that is two thirds of the table, an index scan doesn't make sense. But apparently that estimate is wrong so I guess your statistics aren't up to date. Run `analyze xxx` and try again. In cases like this you should use `explain (analyze, verbose)` to quickly see the deviation between estimated and actual rows. Also add that output to the question, more details about this kind of question here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: @IvanBorisenko: No, there is no real difference if you use a transactional storage engine in MySQL (like InnoDB). The "difference" is only about the non-transactional MyISAM engine which can't really be used in a multi-user environment where correct results are important.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I mean that in Postgres one should never use `COUNT(*)` but `COUNT(indexed_field)`.

Comment: @IvanBorisenko, I am perfectly aware of that and am not using MySQL since 2003.

Comment: @IvanBorisenko: that is a myth that has not been true for quite a while. Postgres _will_ choose an index scan if possible when using `count(*)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, ok, I edited the index to tighten even more the selection - to give the records after 1 Jan 2016, i.e. 2%. I also saw that `6509853` high estimation number and tried to set statistics to 1000 and ran  ANALYZE, still no luck.

Comment: Try to define the index on the PK column (or any unique not-null column): `CREATE INDEXON xxx (id) WHERE created_at > timestamp '2016-01-01 00:00:00';`

Comment: I don't know, if you're trying to use constraint exclusion or index-only scans, but your index doesn't make much sense. Use `CREATE INDEX xxx_idx ON xxx (DATE(created_at)) WHERE DATE(created_at) > '2015-12-01';` instead (and always query for `DATE(created_at)`, not just `created_at`) [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2dcb9/1)

Comment: Thanks @pozs, that way it works and uses the index. Can you post an answer please, so that I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, one of the motivations behind the expression is to reduce the index size, i.e. to group the entries somehow, otherwise I would leave it over `created_at` which is very close to unique.

Comment: The index will probably be smaller if created on an integer rather than a timestamp. As you only use the index for counting, the actual column that is _in_ the index doesn't really matter, but to make it eligible for an index only scan it has to be not-null and ideally unique.

Comment: I get your point, in fact the index is not used for counts only, but the `id` is good indeed, as I need exactly that column (this entire thing is a subquery). I guess I will have to go for a denormalised cached flag somewhere in the upper tables instead. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed the `created_at` usage in your queries (with `DATE(created_at)`) and in your index definition too.

To ensure, all your queries use your index (with [index only scan](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index-scanning.html)) you should use the same expression/column in both the index' expression and in the index' `WHERE` clause ([partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html)).

F.ex:

```
CREATE INDEX xxx_idx ON xxx (DATE(created_at)) WHERE DATE(created_at) > '2015-12-01';
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2dcb9/1)

Then, if you query for `DATE(created_at)` the index will be used -- most likely: there is still a chance that it won't get used, when PostgreSQL's engine decides that a sequential scan is faster (the index will be used when it's [*significantly smaller than its table*](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F)).

Your original index will only be used, when you explicitly filter for the index' `WHERE` clause too (with `DATE(created_at) > '2015-12-01' AND created_at > '2015-12-01'`).

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e52c4/2)